# Is it possible to use this SWITCH PARTITION control option with Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, azure-sql-database, sql-grant

I'm doing some ETL, using the standard "Pre-Load" partition pattern: Load the data into a dated partition of a `loading` table, then SWITCH that partition into the `live` table.

I found these options for the SWITCH command:

```
ALTER TABLE [myLoadingTable] SWITCH PARTITION @partNum TO [myLiveTable] PARTITION @partNum -- Move the New Data in.
    WITH ( WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY ( MAX_DURATION = 1 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS ))
```

Those options seem like valuable things to define (even if they wouldn't be needed during normal operation).

Unfortunately, when I try to run that, I get:

> Sql error number: 11423.
>
> Error Message: User does not have permission to use the ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS option.

Further reading confirms that this is appropriate: ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

> `BLOCKERS`
> Kill all user transactions that currently block the `SWITCH` or online index rebuild DDL operation so that the operation can continue.
>
> Requires `ALTER ANY CONNECTION` permission.

But when I try to `GRANT` the relevant user that permission I get an error:

```
GRANT ALTER ANY CONNECTION TO [myAdfUser]
```

> Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.

I'm using (AFAIK) a normal Azure SQL Server database.

---

**Is there any work around for this?** Or is it just not possible for me to use these options on this Database?

Comment: If you *are* using Azure SQL Database, then what the error is telling you is true. Azure SQL Databases are what are known as Partially Contained databases; things like their `USER` objects have their own Password and the `LOGIN` objects on the server aren't used for connections. The `CONNECTION` permission is a server level permission, and thus not supported in Azure SQL Databases.

Comment: @Larnu I'd be happy with that as an actual answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks the question was solved by @Larnu's comment, just add it as an answer to close the question.

> If you are using Azure SQL Database, then what the error is telling you is true. Azure SQL Databases are what are known as Partially Contained databases; things like their USER objects have their own Password and the LOGIN objects on the server aren't used for connections. The CONNECTION permission is a server level permission, and thus not supported in Azure SQL Databases.